# How to connect to a different database in OpenERP?

Tags: python, xml-rpc, odoo

How would one go about connecting to a different database based on which module is being used? Our scenario is as follows:

We have a standalone application with its own database on a certain server and OpenERP running on different server. We want to create a module in OpenERP which can utilise entities on the standalone application server rather than creating its own entities in its own database, is this possible? How can we change the connection parameters that the ORM uses to connect to its own database to point to a different database?

Ofcourse, one way is to use the base_synchro module to synchronise the required entities between both database but considering the large amount of data, we don't want duplication. Another way is to use xmlrpc to get data into OpenERP but that still requires entities to be present in OpenERP database.

How can we solve this problem without data duplication? How can a module in OpenERP be created based on a different database?

Answer (score 1):

One way to connect to an external application is to create a *connector* module. There are already several connector modules that you can take a look at:

- the thunderbird and outlook plugins
- the joomla and magento modules
- the 'event moodle' module

For example, the joomla connector uses a joomla plugin to handle the communication between OpenERP and joomla. The communication protocol used is XML-RPC but you can choose any protocol you want. You can even choose to connect directly to the external database using the psycopg2 modules (if the external database is using Postgresql) but this is not recommended. But perhaps you don't have the choice if this external application has no connection API.

You need to know what are the available ways to connect to this external application and choose one of these. Once you have chosen the right protocol, you can create your OpenERP module.

You can map entities stored on the external application using osv.TransientModel objects (formerly known as osv memory). The tables related to these objects will still be created in the OpenERP database but the data is volatile (deleted after some time).